# Is there a block that falls when stepped on in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a block that would automatically drop to the ground when the player steps on it?

I googled for a solution but didn't find one. It should be possible to accomplish something similar with redstone and pistons, but being very new to Minecraft I wonder if there is a much simpler and more elegant way.

Comment: To what lengths are you willing to go, in order to place such a block? It is doable, but requires building a special machine with a couple thousand powered rails. Look up 'update suppressor'.

Comment: I was thinking of something much easier than that. I know that some blocks like sand will fall because of gravity. The block that I'm looking for would have gravity disabled until  the player steps on it.  Also, any idea why my question was downvoted?

Comment: The only blocks with gravity are sand, red sand, gravel, the concrete powders, and anvils. (I probably forgot a few but they all behave the same anyway)

Comment: @user1566515 There is nothing "much easier than that" - possibly some commands, although I doubt it would be easy even with them. It used to be rather easy to get sand to float, and fall once updated (e.g. by a piece of string on top) - by placing it on top of a 2-tall flower then breaking the bottom half of the flower. But it no longer works, so - sorry.

Comment: @user1566515 Your question was downvoted because it fails to shows research effort. Provide evidence that you've tried to help yourself before turning to Arqade for help to greatly reduce your chance of getting downvoted. We are not a forum, we are a knowledge base. Your first instinct when seeking help on Arqade should be to search for an existing question, asking should only be a secondary action if you cannot find an answer even after searching.

Comment: You could do something like have a pufferfish player detector and when it blows up, use a piston to break all the signs holding some sand up

Answer (score 3):

A sand block with string on top of it will act like this, but can only be placed with commands.

Comment: no, i believe you can use some fancy tricks in a few versions to place it without commands

Comment: In some versions, but not the latest ones.

Comment: what command that would be?

Comment: /setblock, or //replace in we

Answer (score 0):

yes, and no...
you can use a trick using sand which i will explain in detail, but you need string over all the blocks, which is not easy to hide... however, in the 1.17 update there is a block which automatically retracts when stepped on.
There is a trick that works in any version: put a layer of grass three blocks below where you want your trap. Put a two tall flower on all these grass blocks, then put sand, gravel, concrete powder or any block affected by gravity on top of these two tall flowers, and then break the bottom layer of all the flowers. Then, you can remove the grass. TAKE CARE: any block update to any of the trapped blocks will cause them to all fall down.
This is also how the action mechanism works: if you put string on top of the blocks, anybody stepping on them will fall. If you already put a chest on top of the sand/gravel... before breaking the flowers, opening the chest will make the blocks fall.
Hope this helped!

Comment: The 2-tall flower trick doesn't work since at least 1.13